# I can't fill a PDF form with pdftk-php

Tags: php, forms, pdf

I've created a PDF with form-fields. Now i want to fill out the PDF formular in PHP. I've tried pdftk-php, but when its return the PDF it's damaged. 
What to do? It will be good with some examples :)

```
require('pdf/pdftk-class.php');

    $pdfmaker = new pdftk_php;

    $fields_hidden = array(); 
    $fdf_data_strings= array("co_navn" => "test");
    $fields_readonly = array(); 

    $pdf_filename = "test.pdf";
    $fdf_data_names = array();
    $pdf_original = "Indberetningsskema.pdf";
    $pdfmaker->make_pdf($fdf_data_strings, $fdf_data_names, $fields_hidden, $fields_readonly, $pdf_original, $pdf_filename);
```

// Thomas Bolander

Comment: Did you create a form using AcroForm technology or based on the XML Forms Architecture (XFA). Also: PdfTk is based on a mighty old iText version. There are plenty of things that weren't supported in those old days. See http://lowagie.com/itext2

Comment: Hmm.. i'm really don't know nothing about PDF's. I created the form in Adobe Acrobat X Pro .. :)

Comment: So you probably created an XFA form using Adobe LiveCycle Designer. Then again, you're not showing use the PDF, so we can't be sure.

Comment: http://jobpatruljen-app.c-y.dk/Indberetningsskema.pdf

Comment: OK, I can confirm that you have created an AcroForm based form and that there's a field named co_navn in that form. I can't help you with PdfTk though. I'm not responsible for the fact that they forked an old version of my software.

Comment: Ok! But Do you have a method I can use to create the PDF?

Comment: You have a perfectly good PDF; why would you create another one? What you need, is good software to fill out your form. As I'm the creator of iText, I can't endorse PdfTk because it's a fork of an obsolete version of iText that is no longer supported by the iText Group.